# How can I reload a persistent layout or watch props with InertiaJs, Vue & Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a Laravel project with InertiaJs and Vue3. I have a navigation as a persistent layout which works as expected.

I have **ManyToMany** relation between **Users and Organizers**.
And my **KnowledgeBaseArticle** model **belongsTo organizer**.
Every user can only access articles which belong to an organizer to which the user also belongs to.
The KnowledgeBaseArticle model has a **nested route**:

```
Route::resource('organizers.knowledgebase_articles', KnowledgebaseArticleController::class)
        ->middleware(['permission:view_all_knowledgebase_articles|view_knowledgebase_articles']);
```

So for example: test.com/organizers/1/konowledgebase_articles

And users can **change the current organizer**, so that they would only see the articles of their current organizer, which is a post route, which **redirects back to the dashboard**.

```
// OrganizerController
public function change_organizer($organizer_id)
    {
        $organizer = Organizer::findOrFail($organizer_id);
        abort_if(!$organizer->users()->where('users.id', auth()->user()->id)->exists(), 403);

        $user = auth()->user();
        $user->currentOrganizer()->associate($organizer_id);
        $user->save();

        session(['organizer_id' => $organizer->id, 'organizer_name' => $organizer->name]);

        return redirect()->route('organizer.dashboard');
    }

// PersistentLayout.vue
function changeOrganizer(organizer_id) {
    Inertia.post(route('organizer.change', { id: organizer_id }));
}
```

The current organizer is shared as page prop.

And I have a **persistent layout** for my navigation.

**My problem** is, that after changing the current organizer the navigation links stay the same as before and that the organizer id does not update in the navigation links.

So eventhough I changed from organizer_id 1 to 2 and the page prop changed aswell to 2, the navigation links stay test.com/organizers/1/knowledgebase_articles

My question is: can I somehow trigger a full reload of the page including the persistent layout or how would I solve that problem?

Here are parts of the persistent Layout

```
<template>
                        <Menu as="div" class="ml-3 relative" v-if="props.auth.organizers">
                            <div>
                                <MenuButton class="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
                                    <span>{{ props.current_organizer.organizer_name }}</span>
                                </MenuButton>
                            </div>
                            <transition enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100" enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95" enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75" leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100" leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95">
                                <MenuItems class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5 focus:outline-none">
                                    <MenuItem v-slot="{ active }" v-for="organizer in props.auth.organizers">
                                        <Link
                                            @click.prevent="changeOrganizer(organizer.id)"
                                            as="button">
                                            {{ organizer.name }}
                                        </Link>
                                    </MenuItem>
                                </MenuItems>
                            </transition>
                        </Menu>
</template>

<script setup>
import {ref, watch} from 'vue'

let props = defineProps({
    auth: Object,
    current_organizer: Object
});

let navigation = [
    { name: 'Dashboard', href: route('dashboard'), icon: HomeIcon, type: 'parent' },
    { name: 'Organizers', href: route('organizers.index'), icon: BriefcaseIcon, type: 'parent' },
    { name: 'Knowledgebase', href: route('organizers.knowledgebase_articles.index', {organizer: props.current_organizer.organizer_id}), icon: InboxIcon, type: 'parent' },
    { name: 'Articles', href: route('organizers.knowledgebase_articles.index', {organizer: props.current_organizer.organizer_id}), icon: null, type: 'child' },
    { name: 'Categories', href: route('organizers.knowledgebase_categories.index', {organizer: props.current_organizer.organizer_id}), icon: null, type: 'child' },

];

function changeOrganizer(organizer_id) {
    Inertia.post(route('organizer.change', { id: organizer_id }));
}
</script>
```

thanks alot in advance!

Comment: Try adding a key to your component a using current route.

Comment: thanks for your answer. could you explain what exactly you mean? I dont get it :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it this way.

```
<template>

 <your-menu-component :key="currentRoute"/>

</template>

<script>

export default {
computed: {
    currentRoute() {
        return location.pathname.substr(1)
    },
  },
}
```

when current routed changes key of the menu component changed. it will trigger reloading navigation

Answer (score 0):

I would advise using a state solution. The currently recommended state solution for Vue3 applications is [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/).

It's easy to install into your existing application. Once you have installed it you create a store for your organization/tenancy state.

**state/tenancyStore.js**

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export default defineStore('tenancy', {
    state: () => {
        return {
            currentOrganizer: null,
        }
    }
});
```

Next, in your page component you will update the store with the organizer received through the page's props. It's important to make sure that when the prop changes, the changes get propagated to the store. You can do this by watching the prop.

```
<script>
import useTenancyStore from './state/tenancyStore';

export default {
    props: {
        currentOrganizer: Object
    },
    setup (props) {
        const tenancyStore = useTenancyStore();

        watchEffect(() => {
            tenancyStore.currentOrganizer = props.currentOrganizer;
        });
    },
}
</script>

<template>
    <section>
        Hi, I'm a page!
    </section>
</template>
```

Lastly, in your navigation component, you can once again use the information from the state store you just created.

```
<script>
import useTenancyStore from './state/tenancyStore';
import { watchEffect } from "vue";

export default {
    setup (props) {
        const tenancyStore = useTenancyStore();

        return { tenancyStore }
    },
}
</script>

<template>
    <nav>
        {{ tenancyStore.currentOrganizer.name }}
    </nav>
</template>
```

Alternatively, you could emit and catch events whenever the currentOrganizer changes. I would advise against that approach as things can quickly get messy. State stores have gotten to a point where they're really simple to implement and easy to maintain.